# Threadsafe "put if greater" in map method

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

I have a `ConcurrentMap<Key, Long>` that is a cache from some key to the greatest value for it that has been seen so far. If two values come in at once, I want to ensure that the larger one is inserted into the map. What's the cleanest way to do this?

One ugly way is to write a class `LargestLong` with an `UpdateIfBigger` method, that will probably involve some CAS loop. I don't see a way to do such a CAS loop on a `ConcurrentHashMap` directly.

Or use a `ConcurrentMap<Key, AtomicLong>` and a CAS loop after retrieval. I've heard it's usually a sign of a design flaw to use a concurrent collection against an atomic primitive like this, but this may be an exception.

Comment: How do you know that two values are coming at once?

Comment: @Braj well the box has 60000 connections so probably want to write something threadsafe here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, you should start with a simple synchronized block, identify that it indeed creates a bottle neck, then try to do it lock free. Maybe more complicated solution is not worth the effort or you have a bottle neck elsewhere?

John's solution seems faster but, if this is critical section of your program, you might want to also test the following (using just [ConcurrentMap's atomic methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html)):

```
ConcurrentMap<Key, Long> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public boolean putIfGreater(Key key, long value) {
    Long boxedValue = Long.valueOf(value);
    Long current = map.putIfAbsent(key, boxedValue);
    if (current == null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        while (true) {
            if (value < current) {
                return false;
            }
            if (map.replace(key, current, boxedValue)) {
                return true;
            }
            current = map.get(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't see map.replace which does compare-and-swap...  this is a better solution.

Comment: Btw it's not entirely about performance/bottlenecks. Lock-riddled code is extremely deadlock prone, so lock-free algorithms should always be preferred even outside of hotspots. But going from affecting 1 connection to 60000 is still bad - having lots of critical strips in code means it only takes one unperformant callback to cause big trouble. (Which is why arbitrary code should not go in locks.)

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do this is to use an AtomicLong.  You would get the current value and if it's greater than try to replace it, if you fail try again.

```
ConcurrentMap<Key, AtomicLong> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public static boolean putIfGreater(Key key, long value){
     // assuming it's never null at this point
     AtomicLong val = map.get(key);
     long current = val.get();

     for(;;){
        if(value < current)
             return false;
        if(val.compareAndSet(current, value))
             return true;
         current = val.get();
     }
     return false;
}
```

In this case, it checks first to see if it's greater, if it is it tries to set it.  If it fails to set it (another thread beat that thread)  then it will try again IFF it is greater than the updated value.

> I've heard it's usually a sign of a design flaw to use a concurrent
>   collection against an atomic primitive like this, but this may be an
>   exception.

If your alternative is to use locks, I would tend to disagree in this case.  If you have any links to that argument I would be happy to read it.

Comment: Pretty sure this is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

What about [`map.merge(key, value, Long::max)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction))?

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value or is associated with null, associates it with the given non-null value. Otherwise, replaces the associated value with the results of the given remapping function, or removes if the result is null. This method may be of use when combining multiple mapped values for a key.

Given a `ConcurrentMap`, you can *assume* this is thread-safe.

> The default implementation makes no guarantees about synchronization or atomicity properties of this method. Any implementation providing atomicity guarantees must override this method and document its concurrency properties. In particular, all implementations of subinterface ConcurrentMap must document whether the remapping function is applied once atomically only if the value is not present.

But assuming your using a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-), then:

> The entire method invocation is performed atomically.

Answer (score -2):

The key point here is the wording "at the same time" I believe. None of the values would be inserted at the **exact same time**.

I would create a second thread and a ConcurrentSet which gathers all incoming data, that thread would be picking largest value from the Set and inserting values to your cache.

Because there is no exact same time, you could only optimize incoming data by observing them at fixed time rate.

Comment: Depending on how to interpret your answer, the second thread is then a bottleneck on the whole application, or it creates *horrible* latency while the ConcurrentSet takes time to "gather" incoming data. Also not sure how a set works since that will just lose track of the keys, needs to be a map again. In any case it's not possible that creating a second ConcurrentMap to do the work *first* then pass it on to the "real" map will solve any problem, it just moves the problem to the second map unaltered.

Comment: And yes the inserts can happen at the "exact same time." A multicored machine can do exactly that. This question is about the best way to manage that.